# Как использовать REST API Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Всё сделал по этой статье https://arjunphp.com/create-rest-laravel-framework/

Запустил сервер php artisan serve

И как теперь получить данные?

Пишу /api/task выдаёт

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

И почему роуты надо прописывать в api.php, а не в web.php?

Я разобрался, надо это прописать http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task/2

А как использовать метод put и delete?

```
Route::get('tasks','TaskController@index');
// get specific task
Route::get('task/{id}','TaskController@show');
// delete a task
Route::delete('task/{id}','TaskController@destroy');
// update existing task
Route::put('task','TaskController@store');
// create new task
Route::post('task','TaskController@store');




public function destroy($id)
    {
        //Get the task
        $task = Task::find($id);
        if (!$task) {
            return $this->response->errorNotFound('Task Not Found');
        }
        if($task->delete()) {
             return $this->response->withItem($task, new  TaskTransformer());
        } else {
            return $this->response->errorInternalError('Could not delete a task');
        }
    }
    public function store(Request $request)  {
        if ($request->isMethod('put')) {
            //Get the task
            $task = Task::find($request->task_id);
            if (!$task) {
                return $this->response->errorNotFound('Task Not Found');
            }
        } else {
            $task = new Task;
        }
        $task->id = $request->input('task_id');
        $task->name = $request->input('name');
        $task->description = $request->input('description');
        $task->user_id =  1; //$request->user()->id;
        if($task->save()) {
            return $this->response->withItem($task, new  TaskTransformer());
        } else {
             return $this->response->errorInternalError('Could not updated/created a task');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать роуты нужно в `api.php` потому что эти роуты не будут доступны через браузер напрямую. Эти роуты доступны для запросов со специальным `header`. Например, используя программу [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (или любую другую) можно слать запросы к api.

Ниже указан закголовок, который определяет, что запрос идёт к API

> Content-Type: application/json

Вместе с тем каждый запрос имеет свой `Request Method` - POST, GET, DELETE, PUT и др. Он тоже передаётся  запросом.

Библиотеки для работы с api через js - [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), например.

Также все ваши роуты можно записать одной строкой, используя ресурс. Подразумевается, что в контроллере будут методы show, destroy и т.д. Можно некоторые запретить или не писать вовсе. Смотрите [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers) (подраздел API Resource Routes).

```
Route::apiResource('tasks', 'TaskController');
```

Comment: Как добавить статью в базу? Если в action прописать http://127.0.0.1:8000/task то при отправке формы, будет ошибка Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: как папка контроллеров у вас. Например, если контроллер лежит в `Http\api\v1\TaskController.php`, то адрес будет `127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tasks` с нужным заголовком.

Comment: app/http/controllers

Comment: как заголовок отправить?

Comment: Да, пропустил `controllers`. Вы через что работаете с api? Вы как туда запросы шлёте?

Comment: сделал api для своего сайта, к нему и обращаюсь

Comment: метод get работает, а остальные не знаю, как использовать

Comment: я разобрался, надо было вначале писать api http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task